# validate multiple date fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I'm creating a form I have a datepicker and a timepicker for both the starting date and the ending date. 
So in total I got 4 fields. 
I would like to be able to validate if the startdate (a combination of the startDate and startTime) is earlier than the enddate. But I can't seem to figure out where and how I should put this validation.

So whenever one of the fields is edited it should trigger the validation.

I can't seem to figure out where and how to create this validation, i've tried to create a custom validation named method-validation which could retrieve a method from the controller which then decided if the validation was propper, but I can't put it on only one field, because then if i change the other field the validation would not get triggered.

How to get this working?

Bottom line is, I want to be able to take 2 and 2 fields set them together, and compare them, and show a message if end is smaller than start.

Follow up:

The issue isn't comparing two dates. That I can achieve.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="activity.startDate" date-picker>
<input type="text" ng-model="activity.startTime" time-picker>

<input type="text" ng-model="activity.endDate" date-picker>
<input type="text" ng-model="activity.endTime" time-picker>
```

It is making sure the combination of the two field isn't off

Answer (score 0):

```
module.directive('validDate', function(){
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            function  validator(value){
                var valid = true;
                if (value != undefined) {
                  value = moment(value, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('YYYY-MM-DD'); 
                  if (((attrs.validDate == 'start') && (value >= scope.$eval(attrs.otherDate))) || ((attrs.validDate == 'end') && ((value < scope.$eval(attrs.otherDate))))) {
                    valid = false;
                  }                        
                 } else {
                   valid = false;
                 }

                ctrl.$setValidity('date-valid', valid); 
                return value;
            }

            scope.$watch([attrs.otherDate, attrs.ngModel] ,function(newValue) {
                validator(scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel));
                }, true);                        
        }
    };
});
```

Usage:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="startDate" valid-date="start" other-date="endDate" />
<input type="date" ng-model="endDate" valid-date="end" other-date="startDate" />
```

Let me know if it works. I used the [MomentJS library](http://momentjs.com/) for formatting here but feel free to change it.

Comment: that would work if i only had 2 fields. But i have 4. Both a date field and time field, for both start and end. :)

Comment: So please modify the directive accordingly. It is not very difficult, having this one.

Comment: so you would have a reference to all the other field on every field ? I really can't see how that it would be solved in a good maner that way.

Comment: Somehow you have to tell AngularJS which field are to validate against which. You can hard-code the scope properties names in the validator or something like this.